# Rescue ActionController::UnknownFormat from raising an exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make it so that an `ActionController::UnknownFormat` will not raise an exception report in production.  I'm using Rails 4 and thought something like this would do the trick, but it doesn't seem to make a difference:

**application.rb**

```
config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses.merge!('ActionController::UnknownFormat' => :not_found)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like this was deprecated in Rails 4 in favor of this `rescue_from` syntax.  So something like this:

application_controller.rb:

```
  rescue_from ActionController::UnknownFormat, with: :raise_not_found

  def raise_not_found
    render(text: 'Not Found', status: 404)
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

It should not return status code 404, should return status code 415 i.e unsupported_media_type

```
rescue_from ActionController::UnknownFormat, with: :raise_not_found

def raise_not_found
  render(text: 'Not Found', status: :unsupported_media_type)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`render text` was removed in Rails 5.1

You can use

```
render(plain: 'Not Found', status: 404)
```

instead