# Unable to rescue ActionController::UnknownFormat for formats I don't use

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm joining the many people who want to rescue `ActionController::UnknownFormat` in their Rails applications but are unable to.

I'd prefer to rescue exceptions I don't care about, both to provide better error pages to misguided uses, and also to keep my exception tracker quiet.

The two cases I'm trying to solve are:

1. URLs like `/catalog.xml` (I only respond to HTML requests)
2. Requests with restrictive formats, such as:
   variant. request.formats: ["application/json", "text/javascript", "application/xml"] (usually bots)

The research I've done turned up [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164593) as the best approach but, unfortunately, it doesn't work for me.

In `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`, I have this:

```rb
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound,               :with => :render_standard_error
rescue_from ActionController::UnknownFormat,            :with => :render_standard_error
rescue_from ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken, :with => :render_token_error
```

This works great, except for that `ActionController::UnknownFormat`.

The `render_standard_error` method just sets up some env defaults and renders an error page.

I expected that `rescue_from ActionController::UnknownFormat` would work the way it works for the other error types but the exception is not being caught.

I'm sure I'm missing something terribly obvious here but damned if I can figure it out.

I'm using Rails 5.2.2 with Passenger 5.3.1.

### Update:

I'm actually seeing two different behaviors:

1. When I go to `/catalog.xml`, I get:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat at /catalog.xml
ProductsController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["application/xml"]
request.variant: []
```

2. But if I try `/catalog.invalid`, the catalog page loads normally, as if I had used just `/catalog`.

Comment: did you solve this bug? I have added some suggestions below.

Answer (score 1):

I could not replicate your problem. Here's what I tried:

1. Spun up a new rails app.
2. I created a Person scaffold (with name as the only columns). Then I ran the migrations.
3. Then I pasted the following in my application controller:

Stack Overflow could not get the formatting right so I pasted it here:
 https://gist.github.com/BKSpurgeon/391b0da243b32936334d7989f3e3cadb

Seems to raise and catch the exception just fine?! Please post more information: where are you expecting to raise the error.

**Steps**

- Are you able to manually throw and catch the exception?
- Rails might do some funny things: if you ask for a format that doesn't exist, rails might trip another exception. Are you able to add a byebug statement in the controller where you are expecting to fall, and then watch it all the way through?

Comment: Interestingly, when I raise the exception manually, as in your example, I'm able to catch it just fine, so maybe the problem is not as obvious as I thought.

I added some further details to my post.

Comment: the other option is to post a minimum example on github with it failing. otherwise it's very difficult to debug

Comment: Understood. Unfortunately, this is part of a somewhat complex commercial application and so trying to extract part of it to put on Github would be more work than it's worth. Thanks anyway!